# not getting list of user when I use api in initstate in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to fetch user from an api within the `initState` method, but It does not show user list. Looks like failing to rebuild screen

it worked when I place a elevated button and on its press it fetch data from api..but here I don't want to place any button..it should be shown on loading app

here is my code

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();


}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  List<dynamic> userlist = [];
  bool isloading = false;
  
  void fetchdata() async
  {
    setState(() {
      isloading = true;
    });
    //var res = await http.get(Uri.https("dummyjson.com", "users"));

    var res = await http.get(
        Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'));

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsondata = jsonDecode(res.body);
      print(jsondata);
      print(jsondata['users']);
      setState(() {
        userlist = jsondata;
        isloading = false;
      });
    }
  }


  @override
  void initState()  {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    fetchdata();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      body: MyBody(),
    ));
  }

  MyBody() {
    return userlist.isNotEmpty
        ? Column(
            children: [
              Text('List Of Users'),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: ShowUser(userlist:userlist),
              )
            ],
          )
        : Center(
            child: Text('No user found'),
          );
  }


  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### remove this line  `print(jsondata['users']);`

```
 if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsondata = jsonDecode(res.body);
      print(jsondata);
     // print(jsondata['users']); <= remove this line. this is caused error..
      setState(() {
        userlist = jsondata;
        isloading = false;
      });
```

---

for better programming style. while fetch api, i recommend to use `try{} catch{}`. it will help you to handle if there's any error.
with your current code, the error occurs while printing null doesnt exist value. but you are not `catch` any error. so you dont know what is going wrong.

```
try{
  var res = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'));
 .... here another code

} catch  (e){
   print(e); // here you can handle the error
}
```